# Filtering Eloquent Collection

Tags: laravel, filtering, eloquent

Trying to filter a collection object down based upon any combination of multiple values. This is as far as I've got.  Not happening. Any clues for me?

```
public function search()
{
    $posts = Posting::all();

    $type_id = Input::get('type_id');
    $country_id = Input::get('country_id');
    $province_id = Input::get('province_id');

    $posts = $posts->filter(function($post)
    {
      if( !empty($type_id) && $type_id>0 )
      {
        return $post->where('type_id','=',$type_id);
     }
    })->values();

    $posts = $posts->filter(function($post)
    {
      if( !empty($country_id) && $country_id>0 )
      {
        return $post->where('country_id','=',$country_id);
      }
    })->values();

    $posts = $posts->filter(function($post)
    {
      if( !empty($province_id) && $province_id>0 )
      {
        return $post->where('province_id','=',$province_id);
      }
   })->values();

   return $posts;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show what Input::all() returns?

Comment: Where is $post declared? You sure you didn't mean $posts when returning the results?

Comment: $post  is the name of the parameter for the closure:  `$posts = $posts->filter(function($post)`.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Would you mind posting the input?

Comment: Input::all() returns just fine: three numeric keys. These are values taken from select dropdowns.

Comment: array(7) { 
["_token"]=> string(40) "wsGaQwJx8ikjOHlIdqj3Zx05Lk6zXjXOnNJLg6GN" 
["type_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["org_name"]=> string(0) "" 
["keywords"]=> string(0) "" ["country_id"]=> string(4) "1039" ["province_id"]=> string(4) "1101" ["city"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Check my answer to see what's wrong with your code, but don't use that in fact. Check the other question you asked for a better way to achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should really do a validation for the `id` being larger than 0, if they were provided. You shouldn't be manually checking that out.

But anyhow, why are you using filter, when you can just directly use Eloquent (I omitted the check for id being bigger than 0):

```
$type_id     = Input::get('type_id');
$country_id  = Input::get('country_id');
$province_id = Input::get('province_id');

$query = Posting::query();

if ( ! empty($type_id))     $query->whereTypeId($type_id);

if ( ! empty($country_id))  $query->whereCountryId($country_id);

if ( ! empty($province_id)) $query->whereProvinceId($province_id);

return $query->get();
```

Comment: When I attempt to use this code modifying the last line to `$posts = $query->get()` $posts is always undefined.  Oh, nuts. My data is actually nested:  The fields I want to filter on are in $posting->profile->type_id, etc.  Now what do I do?  $query->profile->whereTypeId($type_id)  ?

Comment: Please consider looking at the follow up question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976917/eloquent-filtering-of-nested

Comment: I replied in the other post

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to return something that makes sense from the closure in your `filter`:

```
$posts = $posts->filter(function($post)
{
  if( !empty($type_id) && $type_id>0 )
  {
    return $post->where('type_id','=',$type_id);
  }
})
```

Above returns `Eloquent\Builder` object, which is evaluated to `true`, so.. it really doesn't make sense.

**This is what you need:**

```
$posts = $posts->filter(function($post)
{
  if( !empty($type_id) && $type_id>0 )
  {
    return $post->type_id == $type_id; // bool
  }
})
```

With such code, you will filter the collection. `$posts` now will hold only those items, that match the statement in that closure.