# Eloquent filtering of nested

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship

I have a db modelled like this:

```
User
+ id
+ email
+ password 

Profile
+ id
+ owner_id (FK user.id)
+ type_id (FK types.id)
+ address_id (FK addresses.id)
+ org_name
+ phone
+ email
+ url
  etc

Postings
+ id
+ profile_id (FK profiles.id)
+ title
+ description

Addresses
+ id
+ street
+ city 
+ province_id (FK provinces.id)
+ country_id (FK countries.id)
  etc

Countries
+ id
+ name

Provinces
+ id
+ name
+ abbreviation
+ country_id
```

I am trying to use Eloquent ORM to query a set of Postings from this based upon type_id, city, country_id and/or province_id. These fields are on the subordinate object $posting->profile->address, etc.

Am I going to have to dumb-down my db - flatten out the profile by merging the address data into it? Or is there a way to do this in Eloquent without remodelling all my data?

Comment: Related question though unresolved:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975987/filtering-eloquent-collection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined a relationship of `address` for `profile`,

```
$posts = Posting::with([
    'profile' => function($query) use ($type_id)
    {
        $query->whereTypeId($type_id)
    },
    'profile.address' => function($query) use ($country_id, $province_id)
    {
        $query->whereCountryId($country_id)
              ->whereProvinceId($province_id);
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I have this defined in Profile.php: `public function address() { return $this->belongsTo('Address'); }`

Unfortunately $posts is still coming up undefined.  Arrrgggh.

Comment: This could be because there is no match in the database?

Comment: Nice one. No, there are only two records. I'm certain of the criteria to match either one.

Comment: This is very interesting indeed. Okay. Try to do this step by step. Rewrite the statement above with just checking for `type_id`. And see if that returns anything. And if it does, then add `profile.address`

Comment: I had an error in my view file. With that corrected, I now get all results all the time.  That is, no filtering is occurring. Hmmm.

Comment: It's correct - check my answer and you will know why `with` is not the thing to use for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you filter the table based on constraints in related tables:

```
// we need to pass all the ids to the closure, so use one array for convenience:
$filters = [
    'typeId'     => 1,
    'addressId'  => 5,
    'provinceId' => 10,
    'countryId'  => 15
];

$posts = Posting::whereHas('profile', function ($q) use ($filters) {
  $q->where('type_id', $filters['typeId'])
    ->whereHas('address', function ($q) use ($filters) {
      $q->where('id', $filters['addressId'])

        // both below wheres don't make sense used together, just an example
        ->where('province_id', $filters['provinceId'])
        ->where('country_id', $filters['countryId']);
    });
});
```

It will set 2 joins and check those `where` clauses, so you will fetch only those posts, that meet the requirements, but nothing is eager loaded here (`with` is for eager loading, but it doesn't filter the main model, only those eager loaded).

Comment: Would this work using  `$q->where(..)->orWhereHas( .. )`  ?  I.e., is `orWhereHas` a legitimate construction?   I assume that I would have to call `$posts->get()` subsequently to get the result set?

Comment: Yes, `orWhereHas` is correct, and yes, you need `get` to execute the query of course.